# Is there a way in Spring Boot to restrict access to a certain endpoint unless a form from a previous page is submitted?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here's the normal behavior of my Spring Boot application:

A landing page where the user can fill a form with general information (http://localhost:8085/customers/generalInfo/). Upon submit, the user is redirected to the financial details page (http://localhost:8085/customers/financialDetails) where he can fill another form and submit the results.

My Controllers classes are as follows:

GeneralInfoController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers/generalInfo")
public class CustomerController {

    @GetMapping
    public String openCustomerForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("mainContact", new MainContact());

        return "general-info"; // general-info.html
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveInfo")
    public String saveCustomerForm(@Valid MainContact mainContact, Model model) {
        /*
         *  something
         */
        return "redirect:/customers/financialDetails";
    }
}
```

financialDetailsController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers/financialDetails")
public class CustomerController {

    @GetMapping
    public String openFinDetailsForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("financialDetails", new FinancialDetails());
        return "financial-details"; // financial-details.html
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveFinancialDetails")
    public String saveFinancialForm(@Valid FinancialDetails financialDetails, Model model) {
        /*
         *  something
         */
        return "redirect:/done";
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can access the financial details form through http://localhost:8085/customers/financialDetails without even filling the General Information form, which is totally expected. But in my case, I don't want the user to have access to the 'financial details' page unless the 'general info' form is filled and submitted.

I tried to use Spring-boot's Security. If I explicitly authorize certain endpoints, (which means all other are restricted by default), then the "/customers/financialDetails" endpoint will not be accessible even upon submitting the previous form.(Expected behavior)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/customers/generalInfo",
                             "/assets/**",
                             "/common/**",
                             "/images/**",
                             "/js/**",
                             "/styles/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

In other words, I don't want the user of this application to be able to access the second form directly from the browser by entering the URL. He should have access to "/customers/generalInfo" and be redirected to "/customers/financialDetails" only when the form is filled and submitted. Is that even achievable in Spring-boot?

Comment: You could simply add a conditional redirect in `openFinDetailsForm`…?

Comment: @slauth Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to check whether `openFinDetailsForm` is being called from `saveCustomerForm()`?

Comment: I think you should just concentrate on whether the required data is available. In the end you must be storing it somewhere, don't you? If data is missing, redirect to the start.

Comment: @slauth yes indeed. The data is stored in an Oracle DB. I will try to check if the form data is available as you mentioned and hopefully it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure every field on your user info page should be filled before submitting the form and redirecting to the financial

Generate an ID along with the page of user details and if the user details page is filled and submitted then that ID could be generated in your database.

Then pass that ID as a parameter in your URL of financial detail and in your controller take that as a request parameter, put it in a condition whether it is null or not then pass it with redirection or failing to access without a user detail message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pranay I will give it a try. I have figured out a way that doesn't require performing any CRUD operation on my DB. In my financial controller, I simply read the `referrer` attribute from the `HttpServletRequest`'s header and checked whether or not it is null. 
(Added `HttpServletRequest` to my list of parameters in my `openFinDetailsForm()` method)

Comment: That's looking more meaningful and compact.